# Use Styled SysColor for selected text in TEdit

Tags: delphi, vcl, delphi-xe3

I am using Delphi XE3 to build a VCL application. This VCL application is styled using the buildin stying from unit `Vcl.Styles`.

In the style I am using the SysColor `clHighlight` has been altered but when a piece of text is selected in a `TEdit` (or `TComboBox` or `TMemo`) the default system highlight color is used (defaults to blue) for coloring the background of the selected text.

NB: Other controls use the SysColor `clHighlight` for selected items from the style.

Question: how can you specify this color in the style?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a limitation of the WinApi,  the highlight color used by these controls can't be modified directly. The only workaround is hook and replace the [`GetSysColor`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724371%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method by the [StyleServices.GetSystemColor](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE4/en/Vcl.Themes.TCustomStyleServices.GetSystemColor) function. like so

```
implementation

uses
  DDetours,
  WinApi.Windows,
  Vcl.Styles,
  Vcl.Themes;

var
  TrampolineGetSysColor:  function (nIndex: Integer): DWORD; stdcall;
  GetSysColorOrgPointer : Pointer = nil;

function InterceptGetSysColor(nIndex: Integer): DWORD; stdcall;
begin
  if StyleServices.IsSystemStyle then
   Result:= TrampolineGetSysColor(nIndex)
  else
   Result:= StyleServices.GetSystemColor(nIndex or Integer($FF000000));
end;

initialization
 if StyleServices.Available then
 begin
    GetSysColorOrgPointer := GetProcAddress(GetModuleHandle('user32.dll'), 'GetSysColor');
    @TrampolineGetSysColor := InterceptCreate(GetSysColorOrgPointer, @InterceptGetSysColor);
 end;
finalization
  if GetSysColorOrgPointer<>nil then
    InterceptRemove(@TrampolineGetSysColor);

end.
```

Before

[image]

After

[image]

Btw the [`VCL Styles Utils`](https://code.google.com/p/vcl-styles-utils/) project includes a unit with this hook.

Comment: After adding Vcl.Styles.Hooks to the project the edit controls look great. Only: in the unit `DDetours` I needed to add `{$Q-}` to avoid an `EIntOverflow` exception at startup.

Comment: You can report the issues about the detours library in the page of the project  https://code.google.com/p/delphi-detours-library/